# Downloading Angular or ReactJS web pages

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, reactjs, parsing

I need to write a parser which will collect data from a website which was developed using ReactJS. The problem is when open source code (Ctrl+U) I don't see anything in the code but if I inspect an element a can see full webpage in for instance google inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I)

Do you how can can download html code from the inspector?

Answer (score 0):

I can not speak for React, but with angular if you locally host the site (ng serve) you will not be able to ctrl+u. However, if it's hosted somewhere you can ie: https://angular.io/